# How to initialize a struct inside a function that is given a variable as reference

Tags: c, struct, reference

I'm still somewhat new to c and I'm trying to allocate some memory to a struct inside a function and pass it around by reference.

My solution doesn't work because the struct im initializing there doesnt get passed to the other functions and im getting errors for trying to access memory, that isnt allocated.

Heres the problematic code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct list list;

struct list {
     int x;
};

void init_list(list* mylist){
    mylist = malloc(sizeof(list));
    mylist->x = 1;
}

void free_list(list* mylist){
    free(mylist);
}

main(){
    list mylist;
    init_list(&mylist);

    //use the value of x for something

    free_list(&mylist); 
}
```

I tried doing this:

```
init_list(list* mylist){
   list *temp = malloc(sizeof(list));
   -initiliaze variables-
   *mylist = *temp
}
```

In that case the other functions can Access the struct but i can't free it because i dont have the right pointer. It just says "free() invalid size" when i try to run it.

So what is the right way of allocating memory and passing the adress around in this case?
Also i know that i could just return it but i want to know if and how it is possible by reference.

Also im using clang to compile.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You might want to post code that actually compiles. See [mcve].

Comment: okay, i edited it and it can be run now.

Comment: I tried compiling the code and got 4 warnings, and 7 errors. So it's still not possible to run the code.

Comment: Oh, yea my bad. The main function missed the brackets. I had them in my own code but forgot to put them here.

Comment: when compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )  Note: other compilers use different options to produce the same things.

Comment: regarding: statements like: `void init_list(*list mylist){`  That does not compile!  Perhaps you meant: `void init_list(list *mylist){`   Notice where the `*` is located

Comment: regarding: `typedef struct list list;`  The ONLY thing this accomplishes is to allow you to type less characters when referencing the `struct list`.  Since you are very new to C, I strongly suggest you avoid such 'shortcuts' until you know the basic syntax

Comment: in main(), the statement: `list mylist;` results in an instance of the `struct list` on the stack.  Therefore, in `init_list()` the call to `malloc()` is an error.

Comment: OT:  for ease of readability and understanding: 1) please consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.

Comment: Ye i changed that now. I used (list\* mylist) in my code and it works so far. But i dont know where (\*list mylist) came from. Does it make a difference if i use (list \*mylist) instead of (list* mylist)?

Comment: @RayPIXEL `list *mylist` and `list* mylist` are identical as far as the compiler is concerned. `*list mylist` is a syntax error. The compiler interprets that as `int *list` followed by the word `mylist`, which is an error.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `init_list()`, it allocates a memory block the size of `struct list`, and sets the value of x to be 1. You're good there. But you seem to have a bit of a problem with the input to your function. When you pass a parameter to a function in C, you really pass a copy of it. Changing the value inside the function does not change the value back in `main()`. This means that what you pass to your function must be a refernce to what you want your function to change. In this case, you want your function to change the pointer to a `struct list` when you call `malloc()`. The work-around you're looking for is something like this:

```
int main(void) {
list *pointer_to_list; //declares pointer, NOT a struct
init_list(&pointer_to_list); //passes the reference value of the pointer (essentially a 'struct list**')
free_list(pointer_to_list);
}
```

where `init_list()` is defined as:

```
void init_list(list **mylist) {
*mylist = malloc(sizeof(list)); //sets the pointer called pointer_to_list in main() to the ouput of malloc()
(**mylist).x = 1;

//Note that we never change the value of mylist
//because it won't change anything in main() anyway
}
```